# Remove green compressions in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, occasionally it will compress code (string literals, getters/setters compressed into a one-liner, etc) that can be re-expanded by clicking on some highlighted green space.

Is there a way to turn this feature off? Call me a purist but I like being able to see the code as it was actually written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the **Settings/Preferences** dialog box, expand the **Editor** and then the **General** nodes, and then click **Code Folding**.
2. In the Collapse by default list,  uncheck boxes to the left of the code constructs you want to be displayed expanded.
3. Apply changes.